# Finding minimun on a quadratic form

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $b \in \mathbb{C}^n$, i'm trying to find the min for the following function:

$H(b) = b^\star P b - q^\star b - b^\star q + s$

I know it's gonna be $b = P^{-1} q$, as P is invertible (also positive semi-definite), but i've seen how to reach it without the term $b^\star q$ where $H'= Pb - q$ and it follows from solving the linear system.

But i'm not used to working with this kind of objective functions (or optimization at all), how can i work with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by completing the square.

Try introducing an $a$ and a $c$ like this, and then solve for them to match your expression

$H(b) = (b^\star -a^\star)P(b-a) + c = b^\star P b - a^\star P b - b^\star P a - a^\star P a + c$

Comparing with your expression,

$H(b) = b^\star P b - q^\star b - b^\star q + s$

we see that to match up we need $b^\star P a = b^\star q$ and $a^\star P b = a^\star b$. Because your matrix is positive definite, then $q^\star P^{-1} = (P^{-1}q)^\star$, so we can solve both conditions simultaneously to get $a = P^{-1} q$. We also need $c = s - q^\star P^{-1} q$.

Now we have

$H(b) = (b^\star - q^\star P^{-1})P(b-P^{-1}q) + s - q^\star P^{-1} q$,

and your function is written explicitly as a square plus a constant. The minimum of this function will be when $b-P^{-1}q = 0$, with minimum value $H_{min} = s - q^\star P^{-1} q$ at that point.

It may already be clear to you why $b=P^{-1}q$ minimises the function, but if it's not yet then you can see this by diagonalising the matrix. $P$ is positive definite and hence $P = P^
\star$, and any such matrix can be diagonalised by a unitary matrix. This means that there exists an $S$ with $S^\star = S^{-1}$ such that $P = S^\star D S$, where $D$ is diagonal and every diagonal element is positive. Then

$H(b) = (b^\star - q^\star P^{-1})S^\star D S(b-P^{-1}q) + s - q^\star P^{-1} q$

Defining a new variable $y = S(b-P^{-1}q)$, then

$H(y) = y^\star D y + s - q^\star P^{-1} q = \sum_i \lambda_i |y_i|^2  + s - q^\star P^{-1} q$,

where $\lambda_i > 0$ are the eigenvalues of $P$, and $y_i \in \mathbb{C}$ are the coordinates of $y$. Hopefully it's now clear to inspect that this function is minimised by $y = 0$, which implies that $b=P^{-1}q$.

Comment: An additional comment; if your $P$ is invertible this implies it has no eigenvalues equal to zero. So if it's positive semi-definite and invertible, it must be positive definite and invertible. If it's positive definite it's necessarily invertible, so it's enough to just say that your $P$ is positive definite.

Comment: Okay, i think this is very clear! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Writing $b = x + yi$, you get
$$H(b) = (x-yi)^T P (x+yi) - q^T(x+yi) - q^T(x-yi) + s=x^TPx + y^TPy-q^Tx+s. $$
If $P$ is positive definite, you can take the derivative to get the minimum: $2Px-q=0$ and $2Py=0$, so $x=0.5P^{-1}q$ and $y=0$.

Comment: Looking at the derivative i should look at each coordinate separately? 
Also do you have any referencee i can look up to get used to it?

Comment: Yeah, it kinda makes sense to me, as if i looked at $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @DanielMoraes You cannot look at each coordinate separately, because looking at $x_1$ the derivative depends on $x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n$. That does not happen here if you split in $x$ and $y$ (such an objective is called separable), so here it's possible to optimize $x$ and $y$ independently. So search for separability and optimization for a reference. You could write $z=(x; y)$ and take the derivative w.r.t. $z$ and end up with the same result.

Comment: it would be nice if whoever downvoted me could add a comment with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Assuming $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and calling

$$
\cases{
b = x + i y\\
b^*= x - i y\\
q = u + i v\\
q^*= u - i v
}
$$

we have

$$
H(b) = (x-i y) P (x+ i y) - (u-i v) (x+i y) -(x-i y) (u+i v)+ s
$$

or

$$
H(x,y) = x'\cdot P\cdot x + y'\cdot P\cdot y-2(u'\cdot x+v'\cdot y)+s
$$

or

$$
H(x,y) = \left(\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right)'\left(\begin{array}{cc}P & 0 \\ 0 & P\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right)-2\left(\begin{array}{c}u \\ v\end{array}\right)'\left(\begin{array}{c}x \\ y\end{array}\right)+s
$$

etc.